# Injecting javascript in specific page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, javascript, module

I am trying to inject a javascript file in specific page in my admin form. Currently I am overriding a community extension and so far the backend part of the code works as expected. But so far my attempts to load the script were unsuccessful.

An answer in different post states that there is a specific order when creating the appropriate xml node, a quote from there:

> To load it on just admin dashboard use the (full 3 element) route with underscores as separators to the page

So, I've dumped the following values in my page:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName(); // -> adminhtml_sport
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName(); // -> edit
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); // -> sport
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName(); // -> sport
```

What I've added in my `xml` file:

```
<adminhtml_sport_sport_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>path/custom/script.js</script></action>         
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sport_sport_edit>
```

did not work. As a last note, I would like to ask: ***Can this be achieved by using the `config.xml` file in my custom extension and nowhere else?***. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the layout handle `sport_adminhtml_sport_edit` instead of `adminhtml_sport_sport_edit`.

The rule for determining the layout handle is `{module}_{controller}_{action}`.

Comment: Given that I've placed this code in `app/code/local/myvendor/myext/etc/config.xml` are there any parent nodes for `sport_adminhtml_sport_edit`? Currently I tried with `<adminhtml><layout>` and then my node.

Comment: you should add this inside one of your modules layout file not in `config.xml`. something like `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/{layout_file.xml}`

Comment: So as it seems, I really can't do it without creating the xml file in `/layout/`. I also added the `<updates>` node and it's childs pointing to my newly created file, and all seems to be working fine. Really appreciated, thank you.